# Python subprocess spools too many processes

Tags: python, postgresql, subprocess

Hopefully someone can help, I have a challenging situation that I cannot not seem to script for. My aim is to automate loading SQL files into PostgreSQL.

I wont know how many folders of SQL files I have so intially I check a folder exists and then loop through each file and load it into PostgreSQL using psql.exe

My current code looks like this

```
if os.path.exists("sql1"):
    for files in os.listdir("sql1"):    
    load1 = subprocess.Popen("psql -d data -U postgres -f sql1\%s" %files)


if os.path.exists("sql2"):
    for files in os.listdir("sql2"):    
    load2 = subprocess.Popen("psql -d data -U postgres -f sql2\%s" %files)
```

However this spools so many subprocesses as it creates a subprocess for each SQL file in the folder as well as more subprocesses for each folder.

If I change it to a subprocess.call it will of course seriliase the loading and block loading the files from the next folder, rather than running a single process for each folder.

Does anyone know how I could create a single process for each folder that exists?

In addition to this I will then run the indexes but only once all processes have finished.

I could use load.wait() but that would only work for one process.

thanks for advice and help in advance

EDIT ADDED:

Taking Steve's advice I introduced some threads but it still causes the indexing to start before the subprocesses have finished

```
def threads(self):
  processors = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
  n = 1
  name = "sql%i" %n
  for i in range(processors):
      if os.path.exists(name):
     thread = Thread(target=self.loadData, args=(name,))
     thread.start()             
     n += 1
     name = "sql%i" %n

 def loadData(self, name):
    for files in os.listdir(name):
    load = subprocess.Popen("psql -d osdata -U postgres -f %s\%s" %(name, files))
    load.wait()
```

But the indexing starts before the processes have finished.

Any ideas how to prevent that

Comment: You need to do thread.wait() if you want to block until the thread has finished.  Python's futures module is probably what you want to use to make "run X threads" trivial.  I have added this to my answer.

Comment: Rather than starting individual `psql` sessions, consider using the `subprocess` module to open a single session with a two-way pipe. Read each sql file in Python and write it to psql's stdin. Read the result from stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a thread for each folder.  Then use `subprocess.call` to serialise calls within each thread.

If you want to throttle the number of threads executing concurrently, you should look at Python's futures module.

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    for n in range(processors):
        name = "sql%i" % (n + 1)
        if os.path.exists(name):
            future = executor.submit(loadData, name)
```

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for your response. Please see my edits above and whether you have any ideas on a solution.

Comment: Hi Steve looks like it has worked. I had to install PIP and futures as I am using Python 2.7. I dont fully understand it but from what I can tell it limits the number of processes and waits for all of them to complete before moving on to the next part of the code. So thank you very much.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call` can be useful if you want to detect errors, too.